# Improperly generating an :id in comments controller (nested resource)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to nest my comments resource, and add voting to the comments with **acts_as_votable**.  I am getting this error message when I try to visit the **post_comments_path**:

```
No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"comments", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :post_id=>#<Comment id: 22, body: "test", user_id: 1, post_id: 4, created_at: "2014-10-14 07:28:22", updated_at: "2014-10-14 07:28:22", cached_votes_total: 0, cached_votes_score: 0, cached_votes_up: 0, cached_votes_down: 0, cached_weighted_score: 0, cached_weighted_total: 0, cached_weighted_average: 0.0>} missing required keys: [:id]
```

So as you can see I'm failing to give either a comment or post an **:id??**

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @comments = Comment.order('created_at desc')
   end

   def new
     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
     @comment = Comment.new(params[:id])
   end


     def create
       @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
       @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
       @comment.post_id = @post.id 
      if @comment.save
        redirect_to @post
      else

       redirect_to new_post_comment_path(post)
       end
       end


   def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
   end

    def destroy
   end

   def upvote
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @comment = @post.comment.find(params[:post_id])
     @post.upvote_by current_user
     redirect_to posts_path
    end

   def downvote
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @comment = @post.comment.find(params[:post_id])
     @post.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_to posts_path
    end

   private

    def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id)
    end
    end
```

Here is my post_comments_path view **(comments/index.html,erb)**:

```
<div class="comments">
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>


    <div>
      <%= link_to "up", like_post_comment_path(comment) %>
      <%= link_to "down", dislike_post_comment_path(comment) %>
      <%= comment.score %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
   </div>
```

**routing:**

```
root 'static_pages#home'

  resources :posts do
   member do
     put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
   end
   resources :comments do
   member do
     put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
     put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
   end
 end
 end
```

Comment: You're not giving your :id anywhere to the controller in your routes. How is it supposed to figure out what you want to up/downvote? Normally you would have `get 'comments/:id/upvote' => 'comment#upvote', as: :upvote`

Comment: All that happened when I made that change was the end of the error message changed to: missing required keys: [:id, :id]

Comment: You would have to use the URL <site>/comments/1/upvote where 1 is the id of the comment. That is where rails will gather the :id of the comment from.

Comment: Also, do you have the parent <-> child relationship setup correctly? I see you're passing in :post_id on creation, which is a good start. I'm not completely sure your use of `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` is correct, it might be :post_id, depending on your model.

Comment: Yes I have them correctly, comments belongs_to post and post has_many comments.  So should it be this? => 'localhost:3000/comments/1/upvote' => 'comment#upvote', as: :upvote

Comment: Its seems like there is a better way to do it, as won't I have to change the url when moving from development to production?

Comment: @ 1st comment Yes, except without localhost:3000, that will be up to rails to determine. Try putting this in your address bar: http://localhost:3000/comments/1/upvote and see if the comment with id 1 gets an upvote correctly. If so, your controller is working, and we just need to work on fixing the like_post_comment_path

Comment: I think my routes are messed up now:                            /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/comments/:id/upvote(.:format) (end route) 
/posts/:post_id/comments/:id/comments/:id/upvote(.:format)

Comment: I have them like your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have 50 REP to comment, so here's a light answer:

Try running `rake routes` in your terminal and confirm your routes are a-ok.

Second of all, are the actions up/downvote GET or POST requests? You need to show us your `routes.rb` as well.

Thirdly, try your hand at the gem 'pry' and calling `binding.pry` at each step in your up/down actions. This way you can check each individual line of code and see if it's behaving the way you want it to.

Finally, I think design-wise, it might even be worthwhile to include these as methods of a model class, as opposed to a controller action--perhaps some wise RoR dev's can shed light on this.

Comment: They are PUT requests.  Adding routes.rb now.